# DNN Detection Matrix holding values greater than 1

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm attempting to use the opencv DNN to detect faces using the caffe files provided with opencv. The model is working for most images, however with images that are large my code fails. There seems to be a problem with the return values from the detection matrix, with them being greater than 1 on some occasions. If i resize the image to the 300x300 size as recommended on some sites the model fails completely and can't detect anything.  Code is below, the image isn't edited before this point.

```
std::vector<Rect> detectDNN(Mat image) {
const std::string caffeConfigFile = "deployFinal.prototxt";
const std::string caffeWeightFile = "res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffemodel";
std::vector<Rect> rects;

Net net = cv::dnn::readNetFromCaffe(caffeConfigFile, caffeWeightFile); 
cv::Mat inputBlob = cv::dnn::blobFromImage(image, 1.0, cv::Size(image.cols, image.rows), Scalar(155,155,155), false, false);

net.setInput(inputBlob, "data");
cv::Mat detection = net.forward("detection_out");

cv::Mat detectionMat(detection.size[2], detection.size[3], CV_32F, detection.ptr<float>());

for (int i = 0; i < detectionMat.rows; i++)
{
    float confidence = detectionMat.at<float>(i, 2);

    if (confidence >.45)
    {
        int x1 = static_cast<int>(detectionMat.at<float>(i, 3) * image.cols);
        int y1 = static_cast<int>(detectionMat.at<float>(i, 4) * image.rows);
        int x2 = static_cast<int>(detectionMat.at<float>(i, 5) * image.cols);
        int y2 = static_cast<int>(detectionMat.at<float>(i, 6) * image.rows);

        printf("FIRST: %f Second: %f Third: %f Fourth %f\n", detectionMat.at<float>(i, 3), detectionMat.at<float>(i, 4), detectionMat.at<float>(i, 5), detectionMat.at<float>(i, 6));

        cv::rectangle(image, cv::Point(x1, y1), cv::Point(x2, y2), cv::Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2, 4);
        Rect found(Point(x1, y1), Point(x2, y2));
        rects.push_back(found);
    }
}
return rects;
```

}

Comment: many trained networks only work with a fixed input size (which might mean for high-res images that they're not well usable with that network). Take some research and find out how your detection network works. however you could still split your high-res images in multiple smaller ones.

Comment: Micka, object detection models may work with different input size. At least one mentioned in the topic (i.e. https://answers.opencv.org/question/202995/dnn-module-face-detection-poor-results-open-cv-343/#202999)